# Find the path a bouncing SKSpriteNode will take

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection

I'd like to display two lines when a SKSpriteNode is being bounced around the screen — one of where the node is going towards, and second which is in what direction the node is going to bounce off of other sprite nodes.

Essentially, I'd like to do something like this:

[image]

I can create the first line fairly easily using the velocity of the ball, and the second line would be fairly easy as well, but only if I know where the line is going to collide with another SKSpriteNode.

For the first line, I'm creating a SKShapeNode and setting its path to the same line as the velocity of the ball, but I'm not sure how to find the path the ball will take after it bounces off of the nearest obstacle.

In short — how can I find the point at which a moving object will collide with another object, and then find the direction in which it will move after colliding with the object? This isn't an issue if I know what object it's going to collide with, but short of doing some insanely inefficient brute-forcing, I'm not sure how to find what object the ball is going to collide with and where.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
let line: SKSpriteNode // this is the first line
let scene: SKScene // the scene that contains all of the objects

// this doesn't exist, but I'm looking for something that would do this
let collisionPoint: CGPoint = line.firstCollision(in: scene)
```

For my purposes, there are no environmental factors on the sprite (no gravity, air resistance, etc.), it's moving at a constant velocity, and doesn't lose any velocity in rebounds, but it would be useful if the answer could include a way of calculating the the nth rebound of a sprite in any environment.

Comment: You need to do hit tests to determine what you will be hitting.  You can either trace your line, or do line intersections with your line and the frame of every node

Comment: The direction of the ball after it bounces depends on many factors including the shape/rotation/properties of the sprite it's bouncing off of, the rotational rate of the ball, if gravity is turned on, etc.

Comment: @0x141E and there lies the problem — an easy (or at least computationally easy) way to calculate the rebound before it happens

Answer (score 11):

This is the result we are going to build

[image]

### Ray Casting

The technique used here is called **Ray Casting** and you can find more details in this [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51819678/bounce-rays-with-enumeratebodies-alongraystart) I have already written.

Basically we use the SpriteKit physics engine to determine draw a line and get the first point of intersection between that line and a physics body.

### Code

Of course you need to

- create an empty Xcode project based on SpriteKit
- add a circular sprite we'll call ball
- add a physics body to the ball and give it some speed

Here's the full code you'll need

### Extensions

Add these 2 extensions to your project

```
extension CGVector {

    init(angle: CGFloat) {
        self.init(dx: cos(angle), dy: sin(angle))
    }

    func normalized() -> CGVector {
        let len = length()
        return len>0 ? self / len : CGVector.zero
    }

    func length() -> CGFloat {
        return sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
    }

    static func / (vector: CGVector, scalar: CGFloat) -> CGVector {
        return CGVector(dx: vector.dx / scalar, dy: vector.dy / scalar)
    }

    func bounced(withNormal normal: CGVector) -> CGVector {
        let dotProduct = self.normalized() * normal.normalized()
        let dx = self.dx - 2 * (dotProduct) * normal.dx
        let dy = self.dy - 2 * (dotProduct) * normal.dy
        return CGVector(dx: dx, dy: dy)
    }

    init(from:CGPoint, to:CGPoint) {
        self = CGVector(dx: to.x - from.x, dy: to.y - from.y)
    }

    static func * (left: CGVector, right: CGVector) -> CGFloat {
        return (left.dx * right.dx) + (left.dy * right.dy)
    }

}

extension CGPoint {

    func length() -> CGFloat {
        return sqrt(x*x + y*y)
    }

    func distanceTo(_ point: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        return (self - point).length()
    }

    static func -(left: CGPoint, right: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: left.x - right.x, y: left.y - right.y)
    }

}
```

### Scene

Now replace all the code you have in `Scene.swift` with this one

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    lazy var ball: SKSpriteNode = {
        return childNode(withName: "ball") as! SKSpriteNode
    }()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame)
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

        self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "line") { (node, _) in
            node.removeFromParent()
        }

        guard let collision = rayCast(start: ball.position, direction: ball.physicsBody!.velocity.normalized()) else { return }

        let line = CGVector(from: ball.position, to: collision.destination)
        drawVector(point: ball.position, vector: line, color: .green)

        var nextVector = line.normalized().bounced(withNormal: collision.normal.normalized()).normalized()
        nextVector.dx *= 200
        nextVector.dy *= 200
        drawVector(point: collision.destination, vector: nextVector, color: .yellow)
    }

    private func rayCast(start: CGPoint, direction: CGVector) -> (destination:CGPoint, normal: CGVector)? {

        let endVector = CGVector(
            dx: start.x + direction.normalized().dx * 4000,
            dy: start.y + direction.normalized().dy * 4000
        )

        let endPoint = CGPoint(x: endVector.dx, y: endVector.dy)

        var closestPoint: CGPoint?
        var normal: CGVector?

        physicsWorld.enumerateBodies(alongRayStart: start, end: endPoint) {
            (physicsBody:SKPhysicsBody,
            point:CGPoint,
            normalVector:CGVector,
            stop:UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) in

            guard start.distanceTo(point) > 1 else {
                return
            }

            guard let newClosestPoint = closestPoint else {
                closestPoint = point
                normal = normalVector
                return
            }

            guard start.distanceTo(point) < start.distanceTo(newClosestPoint) else {
                return
            }

            normal = normalVector
        }
        guard let p = closestPoint, let n = normal else { return nil }
        return (p, n)
    }

    private func drawVector(point: CGPoint, vector: CGVector, color: SKColor) {

        let start = point
        let destX = (start.x + vector.dx)
        let destY = (start.y + vector.dy)
        let to = CGPoint(x: destX, y: destY)

        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.move(to: start)
        path.addLine(to: to)
        path.closeSubpath()
        let line = SKShapeNode(path: path)
        line.strokeColor = color
        line.lineWidth = 6
        line.name = "line"
        addChild(line)
    }
}
```

### How does it work?

This method

```
func drawVector(point: CGPoint, vector: CGVector, color: SKColor)
```

simply draws a `vector` from a `starting point` a with a given `color`.

This one

```
func rayCast(start: CGPoint, direction: CGVector) -> (destination:CGPoint, normal: CGVector)?
```

uses the Ray Casting technique discussed above to find the point of intersection and the related *normal vector*.

Finally in the

```
func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval)
```

we are going to

- remove the lines drawn during the previous frame
- get the collision point using the raycasting
- draw the line between the ball and the collision point
- calculate the direction the ball is going to bounce
- draw a line that goes from the collision using the direction value got in the previous step

That's it

Comment: He wants to also check for collisions with other nodes

Comment: This solution also works with additional nodes. They just need to have a physics body

Comment: If possible, you could change the GIF at the top. Currently, it doesn't appear like you are checking for node collisions (in the GIF) and you don't state it. Just trying to clarify for others

Comment: Thanks for your response — this is definitely going to help me out. If you could edit your answer to include how it would be done for all (or at least most) scenarios (gravity, friction, etc.), I’ll award the bounty to your answer

Comment: @Jojodmo Please note I updated my code. What do you mean with `for all scenarios`? Not sure about what you need.

Comment: @LucaAngeletti The code currently doesn't account for any velocity lost in the bounce, or if the ball will accelerate from the current position to the position it's bouncing at due to gravity or some other factor

Comment: @Jojodmo Please note that changes in velocity don’t affect the trajectory.

Comment: It does if the object is affected by gravity

Comment: @Jojodmo My answer simulates a pool table scenario where gravity is along the Z axis. If you are looking for a scenario where gravity is along the Y axis this solution won’t work.

Comment: @LucaAngeletti Exactly — although this answer will work wonders for me, it would help more people if it also works for gravity, (or, even better, any acceleration) along the X or Y axis