# Why Swift cannot enumerate bodies along ray?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to find if there are nodes in some direction starting from some point.

So far I tried `enumerateBodies` function of Swift, but it seems it does not recognize nodes along some ray

```
var block1 = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 300, height: 100))        
var block2 = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 300, height: 100))
let rayStart = CGPoint(x: 2800, y: 400)
let rayEnd = CGPoint(x: 3100, y: 400 )
block1.fillColor = SKColor.white
block2.fillColor = SKColor.red
block1.position = CGPoint(x:3000,y:400)
block2.position = CGPoint(x:2900,y:400)
self.addChild(block1)
self.addChild(block2)
self.physicsWorld.enumerateBodies(alongRayStart: rayStart, end: 
rayEnd) {(body, point, vector, stop) in
    print("here")
}
```

I expect to see "here" written in console but block inside enumerateBodies does not even work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not a duplicate but maybe you can find some useful info [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51819678/bounce-rays-with-enumeratebodies-alongraystart)

Comment: have you add a physical body?

Comment: E.Coms has it,  there is no physics body attached to your shapes, so the physics world has no idea anything exists